# Doubt in the range of variance of First Principal Component

Tags: self-study, pca, covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

This is my first problem on this forum. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0B6X.jpg) is the problem:

> The covariance matrix of a four dimensional random vector $\boldsymbol X$ is of the form
> $$\begin{bmatrix}1&\rho&\rho&\rho\\
> \rho&1&\rho&\rho\\
> \rho&\rho&1&\rho\\
> \rho&\rho&\rho&1\\
> \end{bmatrix}\,,$$ where $\rho<0$. If $v$ is the variance of the first principal component, then
>
> 1. $v$ cannot exceed $5/4$.
> 2. $v$ can exceed $5/4$, but cannot exceed $4/3$.
> 3. $v$ can exceed $4/3$, but cannot exceed $3/2$.
> 4. $v$ can exceed $3/2$.

In this problem, I have been given a covariance matrix of a random variable and I am required to compute the range of variance of first principal component. I am having difficulty dealing with these terms, so I have chosen a specific example where $\rho = -0.5$. So, Now, the resulting matrix is given by:

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -0.5 & -0.5 &-0.5 \\ 
 -0.5&1  & -0.5 & -0.5\\ 
 -0.5&  -0.5&  1& -0.5\\ 
 -0.5&  -0.5&  -0.5& 1
\end{pmatrix}

If I take $\lambda = 1.5$ then this satisfies the characteristic equation ($|A - \lambda I|$ = 0) of the resulting matrix and hence it will be one of the roots of the characteristic equation. I also know that variance of principal component is nothing but characteristic roots. Now, I only have one root at this point and from there only I can see that $\lambda = \frac{3}{2}$ which does not lead to any of the options given. The correct answer is shown as (b).

Comment: Would you mind writing out the rest of the calculation.

Comment: Which calculation? I have mentioned eveything that I thought would be required to mention. Now, If you are asking how did I get $\lambda = 1.5$, then I just thought about this value because If We look at the matrix which I took (the one in which I assumed $\rho = -0.5$), then all the entries of the matrix will be $-0.5$ which means determinant is zero and this would mean that one of the characteristic roots would be $\lambda = 1.5$? What else "rest of the calculations" do see in my question?

Comment: what if p is -1,000,000,000?

Comment: Variance of the first principal component is the largest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$, which in this case is $1-\rho$. Based on the fact that $\operatorname{Var}(1^TX)=1^T\Sigma1$, you have a lower bound on $\rho$ and hence a bound on $1-\rho$. This rules out last two options.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix of $\boldsymbol X$. Variance of the first principal component is then the largest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$.

Now you can write $\Sigma=(1-\rho)I_4+\rho\mathbf1\mathbf1'$ where $\mathbf1$ is a column vector of all-ones, which means you can use the [Matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) to find the characteristic polynomial $\det(\Sigma-\lambda I_4)$ and solve for the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$. Or you might take it as a standard result (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/689111/321264) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55165/321264)) that there are two distinct eigenvalues of $\Sigma$, namely $1-\rho$ (with multiplicity $3$) and $1+3\rho$. This is perhaps easy to remember if you recall that $\det\Sigma=(1-\rho)^3(1+3\rho)$. Because $\rho$ is negative, the largest eigenvalue is $1-\rho$.

Observe that $$0\le\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf 1'\boldsymbol X)=\mathbf 1'\Sigma\mathbf 1=4(1+3\rho)$$

This yields $$\rho\ge -\frac13 \quad,\text{ i.e. },\quad 1-\rho\le \frac43$$

One can also use $\det\Sigma\ge 0$ to obtain this bound.

Combining this with $\rho<0$, we have $$1<1-\rho\le \frac43$$

There is no other restriction on $1-\rho$, so option (2) is correct.